# Dynamic Pages for a Schedule

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic, schedule

having an issue on how I might be able to execute this idea.

Say I have a School that has a schedule page for 30 different upcoming courses. If a course is clicked it opens to a new page that displays info about that course (cost, time, directions, description). Is there anyway to have that content generated by which course is clicked instead of creating 30 different html pages for each course?

Could I used javascript or php? Any help on how or where I can begin figuring this out would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP:

Your main page could have a link `<a href="courses.php?course=1">Course 1</a>`

Then, 'courses.php' could grab the `$_GET['course']` variable and use it to grab relevant data from a database using a SQL statement (`SELECT * FROM table WHERE course_id = '" .$_GET['course']. "'`) and then echo the information out using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 0. Conventional loading a target item.
You may add a href link on the course title or item name.
Then, go to the page.
Considering the most user-friendly UI design, that will bother your clients to go back from the course page. For this reason, recently, this is not a good idea to provide clients with more and better systematized info.

Suggestion 1. Use a overriding page such as lightbox. This will allow you to show just one class info without reloading the whole on its background (parent frame, technically speaking). That's a simple steps as follows:

Step 1. including lightbox APIs written in JQuery and/or javascript.
Step 2. Just a http link to load overriding pages corresponding to a class (target item) info.
Step 3. Add close button/ link or equivalent ones on the pop-up page.

Suggestion 2. Use AJAX to hide and show the existing item. The internal processes will be simple.

Step 1. Add a div block and name it such as "id" tag in the HTML 5 codes.
Step 2. When getting a click from users, call AJAX code to load the corresponding course.
Step 3. Show/ hide it.